# Get Facebook historical public posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-crawler

I have a project need get Facebook historical public posts filtered by Key words. These are what I have found:

1. Most of the crawlers I have found is using Facebook Public Post search API:
   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/targeting
   However, I just started my application and the version is fixed on v2.5, what's more, they removed this endpoint after v2.1.
2. manually crawl the web page. I have tried this it only returns over 500 posts then no more posts back and it's sampled.
3. Facebook historical datasets from a third company:
   Datashift is the only place I have found that it announced that it has Facebook data, however they are not response my email.
4. I have sent a email to Facebook Research and asked for help too, still no response.

Do you have any suggestion? Any thing will be appreciate. Thanks for reading this,

Comment: Graph API isn’t very good with historical data – it is mostly geared towards the “here and now”, and the further back you try to go, the more sparse data will become. Crawling is forbidden by ToS (unless you get explicit permission by FB beforehand.)

Comment: "Graph API towards here and now" that's good to know. I will not write a program crawling the Facebook page because what it returns are not enough. Do you know a third party company like Gnip for Twitter that sells Facebook posts data except Datashift?